# Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one architecture definitions. Found:

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, abi

I am working on `OpenCv` project and I have this `Android.mk` file where I am setting the path for `OpenCv libraries`

```
OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR        := $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)\sdk\native\jni\include
OPENCV_LIBS_DIR           := $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)\sdk\native\libs\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
OPENCV_3RD_PARTY_LIBS_DIR := $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK_HOME)\sdk\native\3rdparty\libs\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
```

When I am trying to sync the `graddle` I am getting this `error` from `ndk-bundle`

**Error while executing process**

```
D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\*****\trunk\iShow\src\main\cpp\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\****\trunk\iShow\src\main\cpp\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/****/trunk/iShow/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\****\trunk\iShow\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one architecture definitions. Found:
*** Android NDK: Aborting... . Stop. Open File
```

I tried replacing `$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)` with `abi-armeabi-v7a` or any other it won't work.

> Updated Question

This is the portion of `init.mk` file in `ndk-bundle dir`where I am getting the `error`

```
# Check that each ABI has a single architecture definition
$(foreach _abi,$(strip $(NDK_ALL_ABIS)),\
  $(if $(filter-out 1,$(words $(NDK_ABI.$(_abi).arch))),\
    $(call __ndk_info,INTERNAL ERROR: The $(_abi) ABI should have exactly one architecture definitions. Found: '$(NDK_ABI.$(_abi).arch)')\
    $(call __ndk_error,Aborting...)\
  )\
)

Error:ABIs [armeabi] are not supported for platform. Supported ABIs are [armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64].
```

**Please Help**

Comment: Which NDK version are you using? `armeabi` is no longer supported in the latest release. Also, `abi-armeabi-v7a` looks wrong. It should be `armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: @Michael it should be `r17b` I downloaded it today. Can you tell me how to check `ndk-bundle version`

Comment: @Michael `armeabi-v7a` is not working either :(

Comment: @Michael though I am using `OpenCv v3.2`.. should I use any specific `compatiable  ndk version` ?

Comment: @Michael yes. That's the same `error` I got. Let me try. Thank you :)